# Node Typescript Integration - MSAL for 365

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, azure, office365api

Trying to implement MSAL in my Azuer/365 project. I am having problems importing MSAL and then subsequently using the imported object. Here is my code:

```
import { UserAgentApplication } from "msal";

const msalConfig = {
        auth: {
                clientId: "your_client_id"
        },
};
const graphScopes = ["user.read", "mail.send"]; // An array of graph scopes

const msalApplication = new UserAgentApplication(msalConfig);
```

When I run, I get the following error:

```
"SyntaxError: The requested module 'msal' does not provide an export named 'UserAgentApplication'"
```

I alternately tried to change the import to:

```
import * as Msal from "msal";

const msalConfig = {
        auth: {
                clientId: "your_client_id"
        },
};
const graphScopes = ["user.read", "mail.send"]; // An array of graph scopes

const msalApplication = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(msalConfig);
```

In this scenario, I got the following error:

```
TypeError: Msal.UserAgentApplication is not a constructor
```

Comment: Second code, with `import * as Msal from "msal";` works just fine Maybe you need to update MSAL?

Comment: Tried npm uninstall and reinstall. Is there some other configuration needed in package.json? Does npm install msal need any flags or configurations??